# What is the difference between getSession, getHandshakeSession and session.startHandshake in SSLSocket.java in 2 way ssl

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

In SSLSocket.java there is one abstract method

```
 public abstract SSLSession getSession();
```

and One

```
  public SSLSession getHandshakeSession() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
```

and once we get the session object from either session=getSession or session=getHandshakeSession

What does `session.startHandhshake` do?

What is the difference between the three when it comes to SSL handshake, especially in 2 way SSL?
When we pass keystore in java during handshake does the SSL session object consider it?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)? and [tag:openssl] and [tag:spring] have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it exhibits no prior research and because it is answered in the Javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

`getSession()`: Returns the SSL session associated with the established connection, including any data exchanged after the handshake. It reflects the entire handshake process, including client authentication.

`getHandshakeSession()`: Returns the SSL session specifically for the ongoing handshake process. It contains information relevant to the handshake, such as the chosen cipher suite and exchanged certificates.

`session.startHandshake()`: Initiates or continues the SSL handshake process, exchanging cryptographic information and establishing a secure connection. The session object obtained from `getSession()` or `getHandshakeSession()` reflects the result of this handshake.

In 2-way SSL, the session objects consider the keystore if it contains the necessary certificates and private keys for client authentication. The SSL implementation uses the certificates from the keystore to authenticate the client during the handshake.